# Difference between recentred and scaled eigenvalues and the Tracy Widom distribution

Tags: r, simulation, matrix, random-matrix

I have been generating correlation matrices from independent normal data simulated using the MASS package. I do this k times and extract the eigenvalues of the matrices. I was interested in comparing these eigenvalues to the Tracy-Widom (TW) distribution.  I have been using the rescaling from "Tracy-Widom law for the extreme eigenvalues of sample correlation matrices" by ZHIGANG BAO, GUANGMING PAN & WANG ZHOU.

$$
\frac{n\lambda_p - \left(p^{\frac{1}{2}} + n^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2}{\left(n^{\frac{1}{2}} + p^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(p^{-\frac{1}{2}} + n^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \xrightarrow{d} TW_1
$$

$n$ is the number of rows of simulated data and p the number of columns.

As far as I could follow the paper the leading eigenvalue of my correlation matrix should match the Tracy-Widom distribution after this transformation.

I was wondering if there is possibly something I missed in the paper that means this isn't suitable for correlations matrices based on normal data.

Using the Monte-Carlo walk method in chisq-test for R returned the following.

```
data:  z and m
X-squared = 39800, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

Which does suggest the transformed eigenvalues and TW differ when the above paper suggests this should not be the case.

The eventual hope is to use the TW distribution to generate a hypothesis test.

Comment: You might get better accuracy if you use Johnstone's "second order results". See [arXiv:math/0611589](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611589)